# Finding sigma of Gaussian

Tags: statistics, gaussian, noise

Is there a simple equation which given the area of the shaded part and the mean, gives you the corresponding sigma for a normal distribuion?

P.S the shaded part corresponds to the area under the section of the Gaussian curve which lies on the negative x-axis. In my application this will correspond to the cross over probability.

Thanks
[image]

Comment: Something which I forgot to mention and I guess makes the sigma unique is that the whole are under the graph must be equal to 1. Therefore enlarging sigma means that the curve flattens

Comment: Sorry but I am not understanding. Are you taking into consideration that the mean is fixed at 1? Because if you move the mean, then you are right, but if the mean is fixed there is only one value of sigma which will give you that area. (at least as far as I know)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do I understand correctly that you mean *area left of x=0*?

Area left of zero is simply *\Phi((0 - \mu)/\sigma)* where *\mu* is the mean of the distribution (1) and *\sigma* is the variance (what you are looking for).  *\Phi()* is the normal cdf.  You can easily (sort of) solve it for *\sigma*:

1. In case of normals *\Phi((0 - \mu)/\sigma) = a* is equivalent to *\Phi(1/\sigma) = 1 - a* (*a* is the area under the curve).
2. You cannot invert *\Phi()* easily but software will just do it.  In R the inverse is `qnorm()` and *\sigma* will be `1/qnorm(1-a)`.

Comment: Thanks. From the looks of it, this might be what I needed. I will test it out and mark your answer as correct once I verify.